# typescript- Sort an array of objects by a field if its not null, and another if it is null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an api which gives response like this (assigning it to a variable for brevity and clarity)

```
let response = [{
    id: 6789,
    pageNumber: null,
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3456,
    pageNumber: 2,
    sequence: 3
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    pageNumber: 1,
    sequence: 5
  },
  {
    id: 8967,
    pageNumber: null,
    sequence: 2
  }
]
```

Now, i have to sort it by `pageNumber` if it's not null and if its null, then sort it by `sequence`. The values with `pageNumber` where its not null should be first though. So, the result should be like

```
[{
    id: 1234,
    pageNumber: 1,
    sequence: 5
  },
  {
    id: 3456,
    pageNumber: 2,
    sequence: 3
  },
  {
    id: 6789,
    pageNumber: null,
    sequence: 1
  },
  {
    id: 8967,
    pageNumber: null,
    sequence: 2
  }
]
```

I looked at many solutions but most of them were in JS. When i try it in TS, like this one

```
response.sort((r1: any, r2: any) => {
    return (r1.pageNumber === null) - (r2.pageNumber === null) || r1.pageNumber - r2.pageNumber || r1.sequence - r2.sequence;
});
```

I get an error saying:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

How can i correct my sorting method or should i do it differently?
**NOTE**: All objects will have `sequence`. `pageNumber` can be null.

Comment: Turn the booleans into numbers first before subtracting them.

Answer (score 0):

Turned the booleans into number, and this worked.

```js
response.sort((r1: any, r2: any) => {
  return (+((r1.pageNumber as any) === null) - +((r2.pageNumber as any) === null) ||
    r1.pageNumber - r2.pageNumber ||
    r1.sequence - r2.sequence
  );
});
```